# binding a datagrid to datatable dynamically

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my usercontrol and i am binding it with a datatable from code behind . using this code :

```
   conn.Open()
    cmd = New OdbcCommand("select dum,I_name from tbl_items where H=1", conn)
    Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("head")
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv_itemHead.ItemsSource = New DataView(dt)
    conn.Close()
```

and the xaml is this :

```
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"  Height="154" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,55,0,0" 
              Name="dgv_itemHead" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="242"  >

    </DataGrid>
```

I want to define columns in xaml and set their data from code behind . 
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` on your dataGrid and can set columns like this -

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ColumnName1}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ColumnName2}"/>
       ....
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ColumnName7}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In binding you can provide `column names` which you want to show in dataGrid from dataTable.